# How do you use shims to map global thirdparty project to scoped object

Tags: sapui5

In the documenation there is an example to include lodash in the project, which typically adds the variable "_" to the global scope. With AMD shims, you can map what is expected (globally) and surface this in the import.

E.g. for this:

```
specVersion: "1.0"
type: application
metadata:
  name: my.application
--- # Everything below this line could also be put into the ui5.yaml of a standalone extension module
specVersion: "1.0"
kind: extension
type: project-shim
metadata:
  name: my.application.thirdparty
shims:
  configurations:
    lodash: # name as defined in package.json
      specVersion: "1.0"
      type: module # Use module type
      metadata:
        name: lodash
      resources:
        configuration:
          paths:
            /resources/my/application/thirdparty/: "" # map root directory of lodash module
```

I was hoping to have the ability (via the shim configuration) to map window._ to what ever I've defined in my "import" (in the example below, "myLodash")

sap.ui.define([
        "/resources/my/application/thirdparty/lodash"],

function(myLodash) {
    "use strict";

```
var MyController = Controller.extend("com.my.application", {
    myLodash.chunk(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 2);
});
```

In RequireJS this would have been defined in [Shim > exports](https://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [sap.ui.loader](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.loader) API to influence this. Somewhere before you import this module, like in `Component.js` do:

```js
sap.ui.loader.config({
   shim: {
     "path/to/module/myLodash": {
        exports: "_"
      }
   }
});
```

Then you can import it like:

```js
sap.ui.define(["path/to/module/myLodash"], function (myLodash) {
   "use strict";
    myLodash.chunk(...)
    ...
});
```

Make sure that `path/to/module/myLodash` leads to where your lodash module is located.

**Update**

In [this blog](https://blogs.sap.com/2020/07/30/project-shims-using-npm-modules-with-ui5/) it is explained how to consume modules directly from node_modules, which in my opinion is the better option.